# How do I stop all playing files in finch?

Tags: finch

my question is, is there a way I can stop all sound being played at the same time with one statement? 
For example if there 20 sounds playing, how do i stop them without having to write 20 statements?

Comment: How do you declare the sounds that you use? Do you have 20 separate variables for them?